# How to fix thymeleaf button?

Tags: bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

Have two buttons like  this:

[image]

I have to choose from dropdown list 'Accept' or 'Reject' and then I have to confirm by 'Update' button.

Here is the code:

```
            <div id="dropdown-accept-reject">
                <select th:field="*{status}" class="btn btn-light col-1 offset-sm-9 font-button">
                    <option th:value='Accepted' th:text="Accept"></option>
                    <option th:value='Rejected' th:text="Reject"></option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light col-1 offset-sm-9 font-button">Update</button>
```

But... Finally I want to remove dropdown list and have only two separated buttons 'Accept' and 'Reject'.

How to change the code to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: You just have to bind Javascript action to the buttons where in you would post something to the server to record the decision. It is independent of whether you use Thymeleaf or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will have a form to post if user accepts or reject the application. In such case update your html as below

```
<form action="#" data-th-action="@{/approval}" data-th-object="${model}" method="post">
    <!-- other form inputs here -->
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="accept">Accept</button>
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="reject">Reject</button>
</form>
```

Next use 2 different method in controller to process each action as below

```
@RequestMapping(value="/approval", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="action=accept")
public ModelAndView accept() {}

@RequestMapping(value="/approval", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="action=reject")
public ModelAndView reject() {}
```